# Deleting more than one same data in array in typescript

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist

1. I want to see a single data as you can see in the pictures[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugqDu.jpg)

TypeScript

```
onQualityControlWareHouseStock(item)
      {    
         alert(item)
        this.qualitycontrolservice.getWareHouseStock(item).subscribe((x:any) =>  {
          this.qualityControlWareHouseStock = x.Result;   
                               
       })
      }
```

Html

```
<select>                        
    <option *ngFor="let binCode of qualityControlWareHouseStock" [ngModel]="binCode.BinCode" ngDefaultControl>{{binCode.BinCode}}</option>
 </select>
```

**WareHouse model have *BinCode* field**

Comment: do you mean that you want a single option in your select?

Comment: The image shows the same value duplicated many times from the service, which should be filtering out the values uniquely.

Comment: This link may help [Get all unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using an Observable you can get the first return with take(1). This will unsubscribe from your Observable as soon as one Value is emitted

```
this.qualitycontrolservice.getWareHouseStock(item).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
(x:any) =>  {
        this.qualityControlWareHouseStock = x.Result;   
}
```

Another solution if you only want to return a Element once but more than one you can
to only store unique entries

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

this.qualitycontrolservice.getWareHouseStock(item).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
(x:any) =>  {
        this.qualityControlWareHouseStock = x.Result.filter(onlyUnique);   
}
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'take' ? Whats mean take ? I have ever been use to pipe my friend